# Exclude negative integers in result

Tags: object, certificate, powershell-4.0

I am trying to check for expired certs. The problem is we leave expired ones on our servers sometimes for reference, and I only want to display ones leading up to an expiration. How do I exclude negative integers in this case?

Example output:

Expires In (Days) : **-25** NotAfter : 9/1/2018 10:56:27 AM Subject : CN=SERVER01.domain.com Issuer : CN=SOMEAUTHICA01, DC=domain, DC=com

Expires In (Days) : **-17** NotAfter : 9/9/2018 3:45:55 PM Subject : CN=SERVER02.domain.com Issuer : CN=SOMEAUTHICA01, DC=domain, DC=com

```
$threshold = 30   #Number of days to look for expiring certificates
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)   #Set expiration deadline date
$serverList = 'SERVER01.domain.com','SERVER02.domain.com'

$expired = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverList { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | Sort-Object -Property NotAfter | Get-Unique | foreach {
    If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline) {$_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude the certificates that are already expired. This can be done as follows.

```
$threshold = 30;   #Number of days to look for expiring certificates
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold);   #Set expiration deadline date
$serverList = 'SERVER01.domain.com','SERVER02.domain.com';

$expired = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverList { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | Sort-Object -Property NotAfter | Get-Unique | foreach {
    If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline -and $_.NotAfter -gt (Get-Date).Days) {$_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} } 
}
```